# What did I miss when suggesting an edit to a Windows Command Prompt question?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

I tried to improve the question [How to copy the contents in cmd prompt to notepad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22419803/2738262) in two ways: to improve its English language usage and to bring it on-topic by explicitly stating how it relates to programming tools. Yet three Stack Overflow users [rejected it](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10563724), commenting:

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

I know I'm supposed to fix *all* problems with the post when suggesting an edit. I guess I must have missed at least one problem; which was it or were they? Or were these reject votes intended to send a message to the effect "wait a few months until you have reached 2000 reputation before improving this question instead of bugging those who watch this queue"?

Comment: Any edit is liable to ruin the extra special invisible magic mystery in this question that got 14 people to upvote it.  Google "turd polishing".

Comment: Editing an off-topic question in a way that doesn't bring it back on topic will get your edit rejected.  (Put another way, you fixed all the problems and the question still doesn't belong here.)  Don't waste your time on these questions -- there are plenty of on-topic questions that could use editing.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom That's what I meant by "and to bring it on-topic by explicitly stating how it relates to programming tools".

Comment: I don't feel your edit accomplished that; it's a question about cmd.exe, regardless of the content being copied out of it, and it belongs on Super User.  If your edit was accepted and I saw it in the reopen queue, I would have chosen to leave it closed.

Comment: What?  14 upvotes for something that can be found by trial/error in 60 secs and by Googling in ten?  FFS, it's barely on-topic:(

Comment: @MartinJames The thread is currently ranked 4th place when I google "how to copy text from command prompt". So one of the reasons you can find the answer by googling is because of the answers here on this Stack Overflow question. Edit: Not to say that it's on-topic, but I don't feel like it should be deleted either.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister Well, the question [already exists on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/295370/how-to-copy-text-in-the-windows-command-line-cmd), with a couple of dups pointing at it for good measure.  Google can probably figure it out.